# Timed out on Words With Friends 2

Tags: words-with-friends

If I don't play Words With Friends 2 for a while so it "times out", does that mean it counts as a loss for me?

Answer (score 2):

In words with friends two if you time out (after 10 days of non-play and after your opponent nudges you) it's considered a loss for you because non play is considered "Resigning".

In your game log it'll actually register the game as "You/They Timed Out". After you play with an opponent 3 times and they time out all 3 times you receive the option to block future game requests from them.